# Import Excel files into R

Tags: r

I have to import an Excel file into R but every tutorial I've found so far are about simple datasheets and mine is a bit more complicated. Can you help me with this?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R5sVaP20MDLlaY6TLesrCj664wJYUhDG/view?usp=sharing

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: There are a couple of options depending on how often you'll need to perform the import.  The simplest is to skip the first couple of rows and read the data without any headers, then manually create the column names in R.  Try this and then revise your question if you need more help.  You will need to specify which package you are using to import from Excel.

Comment: This question triggered a discussion on MetaStackoverflow. You should read [Tyler's answer there (link)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368199/146325) because it could solve your problem, as well as giving some insight into how the StackOverflow community works.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(xlsx)
library(zoo)

# Read the dataset starting form the 3rd line
df <- read.xlsx("SO.xlsx", 1, header=TRUE,startRow=3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Clean the data to remove the lines that should not be there
# like the lines 4 and 66 in this dataset
# this could be done many ways. Here I assume that all columns starting from the third 
# should have some values
df <- df[!is.na(df$hallos),]

# Assign the names to the first 2 columns
names(df)[1:2] <- c( "year", "type")

# The last 2 rows are summaries, so we probably want to remove them
df <- df[!grepl("",df$type),]

# The first column "year" has many missing values. We need to add year values to each cell:
df$year <- na.locf(df$year)
```

**Warning**: the following result is missing some characters with accents due to limitations of the format of this text box, but within R environment the names of the columns and  symbols within type column will display correctly.

```
# Result
head(df)
#   year type  hallos  slyos.   knny sszesen  meghalt  slyosan  knnyen  sszesen.1
# 2 2013    J      28     255    622      905      33      300     870       1203
# 3 2013    F      31     223    527      781      34      248     764       1046
# 4 2013    M      34     274    691      999      34      320     971       1325
# 5 2013    A      36     349    757     1142      42      392    1090       1524
# 6 2013   Mj      52     436    902     1390      54      501    1241       1796
# 7 2013    J      39     455   1004     1498      41      509    1414       1964
```